# When to use Future.handleexception in Dart and when to try-catch

Tags: dart

I'm trying to really get Futures in Dart and I've noticed that just about every example I come across uses handleException to deal with exceptions that complete the Future. Yet the API documentation states "In most cases it should not be necessary to call handleException, because the exception associated with this Future will propagate naturally if the future's value is being consumed. Only call handleException if you need to do some special local exception handling related to this particular Future's value."

So when would I need "special local exception handling"? Could someone explain that in a bit more detail? Is there some code that I honestly can't run easily by letting the exception propagate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mads Ager gave me this answer:

Basically, this is the equivalent of having a try-catch in straight-line code:

```
int doSomethingElse() {
  try {
    return thisMightFail();
  } catch(e) {
    return -1;
  }
}

void doSomething() {
  int value = doSomethingElse();
  // operate on value
}
```

With Futures it is something like this (not tested):

```
Future<int> doSomethingElse() {
  return thisMightFail().transformException((e) => -1);
}

void doSomething() {
  doSomethingElse().then((value) {
    // operate on value
  });
}
```

So this is for local exception handling instead of global exception handling. If you never use handleException or transformException that would correspond to always dealing with exceptions at the top level in non-async code.

Comment: I see. So the "special" local exception handling is actually just regular local exception handling. Thanks!